# offsetof: seeking clarification of officialese

Tags: c++, offsetof

With reference to [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

would appreciate a simpler explanation of the following:

> The expression `offsetof(type, member)` is never [type-dependent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Dependent_types) and it
>   is value-dependent if and only if *type* is dependent.

Comment: Basically, it says that the type of `offsetof` invocation is always the same regardless of its arguments; but the value depends on `type`, which is significant in a template when `type` depends on template arguments.

Comment: Or when, and if, the member is overloaded and the type depends on its value. (which seems like it would be limited to the template case you describe)

Comment: If you're using `offsetof` you're writing hackerhead C code. In C++ `offsetof` has many problems, and you should use a pointer-to-member instead.